# How to hide/remove some patternlayout

Tags: c#, log4net

Currently, I'm using log4net to log/track more information.

Here is the sample for what this tool logged:

```
INFO  MachineName: SERVER2012R3     CreatedDateTime: 11/2/2015 11:43:11 AM     Message: Loop at time: 11/02/2015 11:43:11     ProcessId: 4052     ProcessName: Business.vshost
```

And here is the configuration:

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="Logs\ScheduleService.log"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="5000KB"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
  <encoding value="unicode" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5level %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

So, now I want to hide/remove some pattern as MechineName, ProcessID, ProcessName. How to configure them?

Comment: There is a informative explanation about how to change this logging pattern: http://www.beefycode.com/post/log4net-tutorial-pt-4-layouts-and-patterns.aspx

Comment: It looks like you have changed pattern "ConversionPattern" but logs still display in wrong format. You could make some mistake during log4net configuration - that's why it doesn't applied.

Comment: Thank Andrii Tsok for your advice.

Comment: Please share c# code where you configure the logger.